# how to consume a SOAP request with ssl certificate in Power Automate Desktop?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am working with Power Automate Desktop Version. over there I have to make a SOAP svc request but this request need SSL certificate in the request. I am able to find out this SSL request in cloud version but there is no option with Desktop version after spending 3 days.

is there any way to send SSL certificate in Power Automate desktop version?

Thanks in Advance!!